# Custom ESP32 Board with JTAG only Programming Concerns

Tags: microcontroller, pcb-design, esp32, debugging, jtag

Due to the limitation of UART pins available I built a board using the esp3-mini-1 module that can only be programmed using JTAG (through Segger J-Link programmer), but I were unable to flash it (Error: JTAG scan chain interrogation failed: all ones) which I found out that the module comes flashed by default (AT firmware) using the TDI/TDO pins that are needed for programming. With that information, is it still possible to continue purely dependent on JTAG without the need to use the UART method to erase the flash first? I was thinking of making the board enter boot mode when the JTAG connector is used but I am not sure if it would operate normally under these conditions.

Comment: "JTAG scan chain interrogation failed: all ones" This error indicates that you have either incorrectly wired the JTAG adapter, are not providing sufficient power to the ESP32 or that the current firmware disables the JTAG peripheral. The last one can be avoided by keeping the ESP32 under reset until JTAG has connected.

Comment: You easily remap the serial gpio and keep the bootloader serial pins free/accessible.  This would be simpler than resorting to jtag methinks.